# How do I greate generic CURD for laravel resourceful controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I find myself writing same code for my resourceful controllers. Is there is a way to extract the the functions index(), create(), update(), show(), edit() & destroy() into a generic file ? Also, if we do that, will it give me an option to override the those functions in the respective controller?

Comment: Google "Dependency inversion principle and laravel", give it a try and when you find some problemes , post an other question with code ., it's always better to try then ask (in SO)

Comment: can you check it : https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator
it think it should be your solution at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a crud generator package like [nvd crud generator](https://github.com/engrnvd/laravel-crud-generator). It creates working templates for controller, model and views which you can [edit yourself](https://github.com/engrnvd/laravel-crud-generator#customizing-nvd-crud-generator) to suite your needs. This solution will save you the trouble of writing the same code again and again with the flexibilty of customizing each controller.

However, if you need to have a generaic controller which you can extend from, you can do that as well. You can create a controller `ResourceController` with `artisan` `make` command and then extend all other resource controllers from it.